# Reading ASCII characters from a file in C

Tags: c, ascii

I am printing the first 128 ASCII characters in a file and then trying to read those characters printing their ASCII decimal value.

I tried using fread() and fscanf() functions but both stop after reading first 25 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char ch;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("a.txt","w+");
    for(i=0;i<128;i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp,"%c",i);
    }
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);
    while(fread(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, fp))
        printf("%d\n",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be the decimal value of the first 128 ASCII characters but the actual output only have decimal value of first 25 ASCII characters.

Comment: Note: ASCII has only 128 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you reached `26` the system treated that value as an end-of file marker. All 128 bytes were written but on reading it stopped at value `0x1A` (26). This behaviour is for a text file (Windows).

I opened the file in binary mode, and it worked.

```
fp = fopen("a.txt", "wb+");
```

If `t` or `b` is not given in `mode`, the default translation mode is defined by the global variable `_fmode`.

Aside: you should check the return value from `fopen`. If it is `NULL` the file could not be opened. You should `fclose` the file too.

Comment: Why the system treated `26` as an end-of file marker?

Comment: @EsmaeelE it is also the value of the Crtl-Z key press, used to indicate EOF from the keyboard (Windows). That value is by definition, in the same way that 13 or Ctrl-M is carriage return.